# Ruby on rails Authlogic gem and Password_Reset without ending in Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, authlogic, reset, reset-password

I followed this [password_reset tutorial](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic) and was able to get it working. But there are a few things I don't like about it that I want to change.

1. I'd like it to say `password_reset` rather than `reset_passwords` in the url. Which I've managed to accomplish by renaming the controller and routing it in `config/routes.rb` as `map.resources :reset_passwords, :as => 'reset_password', :only => [:index, :create, :edit, :update]`
2. I'd like to have `domain.com/password_reset` to link to the `password_reset` page, rather than having `domain.com/password_reset/new`
   I was able to do this by changing it so that the view with the form where you enter your email is no longer "new" but "index".
3. I'd like to have it so when the user is emailed with the `perishable_token`, it gives them a url like `domain.com/password_reset/perishable_token` or `domain.com/verify_password_reset/perishable_token` rather than `domain.com/password_reset/perishable_token/edit`.
   Or at the least I'd like to have it as `domain.com/password_reset/perishable_token/verify`

I cannot figure out how to get the third one to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to change it to `domain.com/password_reset/perishable_token` rather than `domain.com/password_reset/perishable_token/edit`. I simply took the code from the Edit view and placed it in the Show view.